# Writing a while loop / for loop for ingredients.

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

This is from a textbook, which I am studying.

```
var ingredients = ["eggs", "milk", "flour", "sugar", "baking soda", "baking powder", "chocolate chips", "bananas"];

// Write a while loop that prints out the contents of ingredients:
```

This is my code:

```
var i = 0;

while (i < ingredients.length) {
  i++
  console.log(ingredients[i]);
}
```

What comes out:

```
milk
flour
sugar
baking soda
baking powder
chocolate chips
bananas
undefined
```

Second question:

Write a for loop that prints out the contents of ingredients:

My code:

```
for (i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
  console.log(ingredients[i]);
}
```

This prints out everything that is needed.

Why does the while loop not print out "eggs" and print "undefined" at the end of it -- while the for loop is fine?

Aren't they both supposed to print out the same thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Changing your log to `console.log([i, ingredients[i]));` would have probably would have given you the clue why. Learning to do basic debugging is almost more important than learning how to write the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are incrementing the `i` **before** accessing your value, so you start with 1 instead of 0 and end with one above your last array element, which returns `undefined`.

So you need to run it like:

```
var i = 0;

while (i < ingredients.length) {
  console.log(ingredients[i]);
  i++; //Notice: After accessing the element
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run both of them, it is correct now. But why is there still an "undefined" after printing the while loop?

Comment: JS doesn't throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException, it just returns undefined for indices larger or equal than the length of the array

Answer (score 1):

This is my first stab at a javascript question. The first answer is way better, but here's an effort to try to help others looking at loops, arrays, and variables.

**While loop:**

```js
var ingredients = ["eggs", "milk", "flour", "sugar", "baking soda", "baking powder", "chocolate chips", "bananas"];

var i =0

        while(i < ingredients.length){
            console.log(ingredients[i]);
            i++;
            }
```

**Do While Loop:**

```js
    var ingredients = ["eggs", "milk", "flour", "sugar", "baking soda", "baking powder", "chocolate chips", "bananas"];
    var i=0;
        do{
            console.log(ingredients[i]);
            i++
            }
            while (i<ingredients.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove and Place the i++ on the line below the console.log(ingredients[i]);

Sample :

```
     var i = 0;

    while (i < ingredients.length) {
        console.log(ingredients[i]);
         i++;
      }
```

The i++ was incrementing before the console could print out the data that was found in the first index. 
It started at 0 but change to 1 before you printed that index.

The undefined occur because of same reason. Because i++ was above the console.log it incremented out of the scope of the array. When the i++ is below the console.log it would of going back to the top of the loop and check if it was within the scoop of the array before trying to print it out.

The for loop takes care of the incremental automatic at the end of each loop so that would not have given you any error